# Microsoft Access Charts - Having source from another *.mdb file

Tags: charts, ms-access

So I am trying to create a chart in Microsoft Access. I have my UI in one *.mdb file and my database in another *.mdb file. I am trying to have the chart get its data from the database *.mdb file but it doesn't seem to work. SourceDoc and SourceItem don't seem to respond as I am expecting it to (all examples point to *.xls files) and there isn't an example online out there for something like this. Is it even possible to have the chart get its data from a *.mdb database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create [Linked Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx#BM3) to the table data sources in the data backend .mdb, and then simply refer to these linked tables as the datasources for your chart.

Comment: @killerbarney: Did you succeed?

Comment: looks very promising. I need to do more testing, but I think it does what I need it to do. Wish there was a diff solution than essentially coping over data, but this will be good for now. Thanks!

Comment: I actually didn't use linked tables because of consistency issues. I changed it to use the IN statement so that it can pull directly from the external MDB. An example: `ChDir CurrentProject.Path` `SELECT * FROM People IN ''[MS Access;PWD=mypassword;DATABASE=DB\WMDB.mdb] WHERE name='Superman';`